# Where do the shipments go?

Tags: fallout-4

When I buy a shipment from a vendor (e.g. 25 adhesive) where does that go? I don't have it in my inventory or my workbench in Sanctuary Hills.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your inventory under the category of item you purchased.

For example, I just purchased a shipment of adhesive:

[image: shipment of adhesive]

Comment: I must have blindly added all my junk to a workbench somewhere then. Oops.

Comment: I think the next time you access a workshop (including a power armor station, weapon or armor bench, or a settlement workshop) it cashes in for that amount of that resource.